# dotnet cli command make nothing in cmd after install dotnet core 2.0

Tags: c#, windows-7, .net-core

I have install and repair dotnet sdk 1.1 and dotnet sdk 2.0 preview with visual studio preview, 
Now when I type any command CLI, I have no result.

```
PS C:\Codes\Anna\src\Web\test> dotnet new
PS C:\Codes\Anna\src\Web\test>
```

I have test to run with administrator but this not working.

Or with this command

```
PS C:\Codes\Anna\src\Web\test> dotnet --info
PS C:\Codes\Anna\src\Web\test>
```

My path is :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> (get-command dotnet).Path
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.0.1\dotnet.exe
```

Comment: Can you try typing in `(get-command dotnet).Path` into powershell?

Comment: I have edit my post

Comment: Could you try using the `dotnet.exe` located in `C:\Program Files\dotnet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is wrong. `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.0.1\dotnet.exe` is only used to run compiled .Net Core 1.0 applications. You want to use `C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe`, which will let you run the SDK commands, like `dotnet new`.

I don't know how did the wrong `dotnet.exe` get into your `PATH`. Are you sure you installed the SDK, and not just the runtime?

If you think it could be a bug in the installer, you might consider reporting it at [the dotnet/core-setup repo](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup).