# dotnet commands in cmd freezing. What's wrong?

Tags: .net, windows, installation, command-line, sdk

I'm following a course that instructed me to install SDK 7.0.101 from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0 (x64)

Once installed, in command line I'm supposed to be able to use dotnet commands. "dotnet --info" works and shows my current sdk info. However. as soon as I use "dotnet -h" to bring up a list of commands in order to create an API project, it just hangs and does nothing.

```
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.101
 Commit:    bb24aafa11

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19045
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\

Host:
  Version:      7.0.1
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       97203d38ba

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

In the command prompt, I entered dotnet -h.
I was expecting a list of commands to display.
Nothing populates and I have to wait several minutes before I can shut down the command prompt.

Comment: What happens if you type `dotnet/?`  or `dotnet --help`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 possible problems on the [dotnet side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44473419/20314269) and on the cmd side.

Let's start with check that dotnet is works fine:

1. Check that dotnet.exe exists at path C:\Program Files\dotnet\
2. Check that variable path C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe added to the PATH.

CMD side:

1. Relaunch of cmd prompt can be solution btw (bcs after relaunch shell will track updated PATH variable).
2. If that's not a solution, this can be the problem of command prompt that solved and explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883530/why-is-my-command-prompt-freezing-on-windows-10).

Comment: So if I understand this solution right, my Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\ should be Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet? And if so, why would the installation create the wrong path?

Comment: Check that dotnet.exe exists at path C:\Program Files\dotnet\ and variable path C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe added to the PATH

Comment: If that all just doesn't works, try to simply reinstall :3

Comment: And check this issue because that can be problem of cmd
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883530/why-is-my-command-prompt-freezing-on-windows-10

Comment: Thank you, the issue is fixed! I turned off quickedit mode from cmd and also added C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe to the variable paths. Not positive which resolved it but it's working now.

Comment: Mark that post is solution for others researches pls